# Why do the meta description of my webpage is showing in Google SERP on mobile and not on web?

Tags: seo, google-search, mobile, search-results, meta-description

My aim was to display the meta description on this page to improve CTR - However, I was disappointed because the meta description is only shown in Google SERP on mobile not on Web. Please see the 2 images.

**Please note : The meta description have the keywords search in Google bar.**

[image]

**Here, the below images is snapshot of web, which lack the meta description. Any one please help me get the meta description on web SERP as well?**

[image]

Comment: Your meta description is blank... `<meta name="description" content="">` Also your pages are far to over optimised and is using oldschool SEO. Also your results will differ for the search SEO Packages Mumbai since you're logged into Google. Use [Google Chrome in incognito mode](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95464) for more reliable results.

Comment: @bybe          The meta Description is not blank. <meta name="description" content="BIZIMA&amp;#0153; | Seo Packages in Mumbai &amp; all over India | Seo Packages Mumbai | Best Seo Packages India | Top Seo Package.  (  CALL US @ 0897-62-000-26 )">

Comment: @bybe            Yes, I am not on 3rd, I am on 11th. I knew that. Anyways thank for the informing. What you mean by Old School SEO?

Comment: @dhaupin       Thank you for answering. yeah, I am kinda learning and want my company to be the top and best. I do not intend to do fraud or spam anyone. The technical Skill of my country is far better as compared to most of country. Do not judge my nation by me. We all are learners. and yes, It is a paradox because even the top seo company needs to learn everyday. Thanks :)

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/N20pAEk.png as I said, missing meta description.

Comment: @bybe           Strange - I see it here. http://imgur.com/Mx8In5H

Comment: Ya, I was looking on the home page.... Homepage doesn't have one but results will vary as mentioned by Dhapiun.

Comment: @bybe The meta for the front page is missing, but I think bizima is refering to http://www.bizima.com/seo-packages. On that page there is a totally stuffed meta desc. Google surely sees this and finds it "useless" therefore isn't displaying it for desktop mode. Prob won't display it in any other mode either soon.

Answer (score 0):

The paradox of this question is that you are promoting SEO packages and calling your site "Top Seo Company India" with no understanding of SEO. You're already stuffing metas, already spamming keys, and its not even your client. **Shame.**

PS: to answer your question, Google dynamically displays your content based on queries and location. Metas, descs, page titles, etc will all change per view-case.

Comment: There is a saying, if someone do wrong with wring intentions - god see it and it will punish. Here God is google. If I did wrong - stuffing and all, then let the god punish. I am making sure that I don't do any thing wrong.

Comment: Sorry to sound harsh, but that is the reality behind every single SEO India site out there. We get literally hundreds of India SEO emails a week from OP's just like yourself, with half functioning spammed out sites. Google is god in this case and will most def smite thee for location + inexperience + stuffing.

Comment: Its okay :)  Wish me luck to better out myself. Thank you.

Comment: Ok offering a tip here...won't change Google behavior but might prevent you from being penalized. You need to make that meta(s) something more natural like "Local SEO consultants serving Mumbai and all surrounding areas of India - Call us for a quote @ 0897-62-000-26"

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I will go ahead. The reason behind me wanting the meta description to show up is that BIZIMA with the TM sign so as to catch attention to Improve CTR (as you can see in the mobile version). Will it be good to use at the start of Meta descrp. Will it harm in anyways if I use it in all my pages?